# Android Debug Mode:Is it possible to view raw query or in-built query build by queryBuilder for countOf?

Tags: android, ormlite, query-builder, android-debug

```
 try {
    if (cashAction != null) {
      Dao<CashAction, Integer> dao = TestDB.getInstance(context).getCashActionDao();
       long count = dao.queryBuilder().setCountOf(true).where()
                    .eq(CashAction.LOCAL_DB_CASH_ACTION_ID, cashAction.getId())
                    .and()
                    .isNull(CashAction.STATUS).countOf();
        return count > 0;
    } else
        return false;
 } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return false;
}
```

I am using ormlite in my android application. i'm querying using queryBuilder which returns the countOf(), Is it possible to view raw query or in-built query build by queryBuilder for countOf in Android debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with Android logging but ORMLite has the following documentation about [logging query trace information](http://ormlite.com/docs/logging) as well as docs around [Android logging](http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging).

According to the Android docs, the following log entries should give you what you want:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.StatementExecutor VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.BaseMappedStatement VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.MappedCreate VERBOSE
```

Enabled all debugging:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.ORMLite DEBUG
```

Hope this helps.